# webapp2.Route with optional trailing parameters

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm trying to route the following url but have an issue if name_code is blank.
(name_code is optional)

> class handler_WebSite_Page(BaseRequestHandler):
>       def get(self, product, name, name_code):
>           logging.info('' + product)
>           logging.info('' + name)
>            if (name_code):
>               logging.info('->' + name_code)
>            else:
>                pass

---

> app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
>   webapp2.Route("/web/product/< name >/< name_code >", handler_WebSite_Page)
>   ], config=app_config, debug=True)

---

I would like for all these URIs to go to the same place (handler_WebSite_Page):

> mysite.com/web/product
>   mysite.com/web/product/
>   mysite.com/web/product/name1
>   mysite.com/web/product/name2/
>   mysite.com/web/product/name3/name_code5
>   mysite.com/web/product/name4/name_code6/

FYI: If name_code is not passed I get an error.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a route for each of the patterns you want to match and have them point to the same handler.  Using webapp2 RedirectRoute, you can add strict_slash to redirect /web/product/ to /web/product.  https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/routes.html

```
RedirectRoute('/web/product', handlers.handler_WebSite_Page, name='product', strict_slash=True),
RedirectRoute('/web/product/<name>', handlers.handler_WebSite_Page, name='product_name', strict_slash=True),
RedirectRoute('/web/product/<name>/<name_code>', handlers.handler_WebSite_Page, name='product_name_code', strict_slash=True)
```

Set default values for the fields in your handler.  I removed product variable as you didn't show that as one of the route values.

```
class handler_WebSite_Page(BaseRequestHandler):
    def get(self, name='', name_code=''):
        logging.info('name=' + name)
        if (name_code):
            logging.info('->' + name_code)
            self.response.out.write('has name_code')
        else:
            self.response.out.write('no name_code')
```